# Как заменить определенное свойство в атрибуте jQuery

Tags: jquery

Есть атрибут - `<a onclick="function.blablabla; return:false;">text</a>`. Надо в нем заменить false на true не трогая - function.blablabla.
Как это реализовать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var link = $('a'),
    callback = link.attr('onclick');

link.attr('onclick', callback.replace('false', 'true'));
```